# Querying an Org's CaseComment object via REST + SOQL returns "invalid cross reference id"

Tags: soql, rest-api

I am using the REST API and SOQL to query an Org's CaseComment records, but I'm getting the "invalid cross reference id" error. Most of my search online shows this error occurring during inserts or updates, not queries. We are also able to run this query without any problems against other Orgs.  The query looks like:

```
SELECT Id,ParentId,IsPublished,CommentBody,CreatedById,CreatedDate,SystemModstamp,
LastModifiedDate,LastModifiedById,IsDeleted,CreatorFullPhotoUrl,
CreatorSmallPhotoUrl,CreatorName FROM CaseComment LIMIT 10000
```

What are the reasons this could happen during a SOQL query and what can be done to find the root cause?

Comment: You should never get that on query, you'll need to log a case with salesforce support

Answer (score 1):

Hi welcome to the salesforce stack exchange community.

I've tried to execute your query in my developer org.

> No such column 'CreatorFullPhotoUrl', 'CreatorSmallPhotoUrl', 'CreatorName'

The problem is related to Chatter answers

> URL of the user’s profile photo from the feed. Chatter Answers must be enabled to view this field. - [Case Comments - Salesforce Docu](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_casecomment.htm)

In case Chatter Answers isn't enabled you should query for CreatedByID and use the "User" table.